# Cannot fire form activate event - issue with disabled forms

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a class that derives from forms. In that class I hide the ShowDialog event behind my own implementation that neatly disables all the other forms, displays the dialog, and then re-enables them. It works really well. A dialog is shown, and all the other forms are greyed out.

The problem is that doing this prevents the Activated event from firing when focus is returned to the calling form - which I rely on for other code.

I am assuming that the activated event is not fired because when focus returns, the forms are all disabled. To cover that, I tried to manually fire the event to activate the form

```
if (fParent != null) fParent.Activate();
```

- didn't work.

To complicate things, ParentForm is in this case an mdiChildForm for which the Activated event is relayed from the activatedMDIChild event of the parent form

Any ideas how I can get the activated event to fire in this scenario?

```
    public DialogResult ShowDialog()
    {
        return setFormsToBackground(null);
    }

    public DialogResult ShowDialog(Form fParent)
    {
        return setFormsToBackground(fParent);
    }

    private DialogResult setFormsToBackground(Form fParent)
    {
        List<Form> lstFormsToEnable = new List<Form>();
        for (int i = Application.OpenForms.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            try
            {
                Form checkfrm = Application.OpenForms[i];
                if (checkfrm != this && checkfrm.Enabled)
                {
                    lstFormsToEnable.Add(checkfrm);
                    checkfrm.Enabled = false;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

            }
        }
        DialogResult result = DialogResult.None;
        if (fParent == null) result = base.ShowDialog();
        else result = base.ShowDialog(fParent);
        for (int i = Application.OpenForms.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            try
            {
                Form checkfrm = Application.OpenForms[i];
                checkfrm.Enabled = true;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

            }
        }
        if (fParent != null) fParent.Activate();
        return result;
    }
```

Comment: No repro, but this is certainly very troublesome.  Big issue is that you are re-enabling the windows too late.  At the exact moment the modal window closes, just before ShowDialog() returns, there are no windows left in your app that can be activated.  You disabled them all.  Which can give the OS a good reason to activate a window that belongs to another process.  You'll have to do this *before* it completely closes, so you need the FormClosing event.  Which is tricky, the form might cancel it, so best to have these modal windows implement an interface.

Comment: Yes, I see your point. What about creating a dummy form prior to show dialogue as a wrapper, and then putting the reactivation code in that,. Or is that just extra unnecessary overhead. Might try both, see how it goes.

Answer (score 0):

OK, so thanks Hans for putting me on the right track. The problem did indeed involve the form stack having no activatable windows. To fix this, I had to make a dummy form so that something was always available to catch the focus - which was trickier than you would think, as you need to make it completely invisible and prevent it showing up in the taskbar. Final modified code looked like this;

```
    private DialogResult setFormsToBackground(Form fParent)
    {
        Form dummyForm = new Form();
        dummyForm.ShowInTaskbar = false;
        dummyForm.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
        dummyForm.Load += ((object sender, EventArgs e) => { (sender as Form).Size = new Size(0, 0); });

        List<Form> lstFormsToEnable = new List<Form>();
        for (int i = Application.OpenForms.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            try
            {
                Form checkfrm = Application.OpenForms[i];
                if (checkfrm != this && dummyForm != this && checkfrm.Enabled)
                {
                    lstFormsToEnable.Add(checkfrm);
                    checkfrm.Enabled = false;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

            }
        }
        dummyForm.Show();
        DialogResult result = DialogResult.None;
        if (fParent == null) result = base.ShowDialog();
        else result = base.ShowDialog(fParent);
        for (int i = lstFormsToEnable.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            try
            {
                Form checkfrm = Application.OpenForms[i];
                checkfrm.Enabled = true;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

            }
        }
        dummyForm.Close();
        if (fParent != null) fParent.Focus();
        return result;
    }
```